# Create new helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I have some rails app. For example I have next models: `User`, `Post`.
`User` model was generated `Devise`. `Post` model has columns `text` and `user_id`. Relationship: User `has_many :posts` and Post `belongs_to :user`. I need to determine who is owner of a post. For example owner can edit his posts.
If I understand correctly I need to create some helpers. I am new at rails and don't understand who do this.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "helper" can be confusing.  If you use the rails generators, you'll get a file in the `app/helpers` directory having the name `<model>s_helper.rb`.  Here you can define methods that are directly accessible in your view templates. For example, you might define a method called `pronoun` based on the value stored in the `gender` field of your User model, like

```
def pronoun(user)
  case user.gender
    when "M"
      "his"
    when "F"
      "her"
    else
      "their"
  end
end
```

so in the view referencing some user, you could do

```
<%= @user.name %> got <%= pronoun(@user) %> ice cream in <%= @user.city %>.
```

Of course you can do exactly the same thing in the *model*, and often that's the better place to write helpers.  For example, logic defining a user status might be

```
def status_name
  if created_at > 30.days.ago
    "old timer"
  else
    "noob"
end
```

Then, wherever you can reference an instance of the user model, you can call `@user.status_name`

Generally, model methods are less about presentation and more about logic.